# How to put Java ServerSocket online?

Tags: java, serversocket

I have a Java program that uses ServerSocket to listen for connections on my local port. I want to put this online so other people can also run the client and connect. I just want the host to literally run my .java program in an infinite loop. All the cloud hosting sites talk about Apache, Maven, and databases but that all goes over my head. How can I get them to run my .java file in an infinite loop so people worldwide can connect to the server socket?

Comment: Get yourself a server for a few bucks a month, install java, "daemonize" your app (i.e. so it doesn't close when you disconnect from the server, using nohup/disown/screen or whatever), star the app and voilà. Hope you're familiar with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your own server at home, you only need to contract to your Internet Service Provider and they will give you a publc IP and your server will be public.

Another option is to contract a cloud server like Amazon EC2, they have an option and give you a basic server free for a year.

https://aws.amazon.com/es/ec2/

Or you can contract a VPS virtual private server, it's a dedicated server online for you, it's like EC2 but without virtual machines

Comment: You don't need to contact your ISP. You already have a public IP, unless there's some weird NATting ISPs in other countries.